# GNUPLOT does not save output using PHP

Tags: php, gnuplot

I have PHP file, which I use gnuplot to plot sine graph and save the output, but after running the php file in localhost the output does not save anywhere.
Here is the code:

```
<?php

    `echo "set term png;set xrange[-2*pi:2*pi]; 
    set output 'output.png'; plot sin(x)" | gnuplot`;

?>
```

I use `exec()` also instead of above code, but no difference:

```
exec('echo "set term png;set xrange[-2*pi:2*pi]; 
set output \'output.png\'; plot sin(x)" | gnuplot');
```

However I ran the above code in terminal and the output saved in my home directory.
When I run the code using PHP the output should be saved in localhost directory but after running the code it seems nothing happening. I gave different path to save the output (like desktop) but still no output.

Any idea what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Not enough credit for a comment, so I'll post this as an answer)

Your PHP is probably running on some server, I guess? Does the server have the appropriate permissions to write to the directory you want it to write to?

Comment: I use localhost apache. How should I check if the server has permission or not ?

Comment: Assuming you are on Linux: To learn more about permissions, simply google "file permissions linux". Apache is usually running as a separate user. To figure out which one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509334/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as 
Once you figured out which user apache is running as, check whether that user has write access to the directory you are trying to write.